# Guardar preferencias en local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Tengo unos inputs type="radio" cuando le hago click cambia la hoja de estilos y cambia los colores del index.html

Ahora yo quiero que al recargar la página se conserven dichos cambios hasta que el usuarios seleccione otro input  para cambiarlos.

Para eso quiero guardar las preferencia en el local storage para eso hice lo siguiente:

efectivamente el valor del href se guarda en el local storage, pero no sse como hacer para que al recargar la página conserve la preferencia del usuario, en la variable z trate de obtener el valor del item guardado y reemplazarlo en el href, pero tampoco me funcionó.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```js
// Capturando los value

var selects_value = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for(i=0; i<selects_value.length; i++){
  selects_value[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var mode_value = this.value;

    switch (mode_value) {
      case "normal-mode":
      document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", "css/styles.css");
        break;
      case "light-mode":
        document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", "css/light-mode.css");
        break;  
      case "dark-mode":
        document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", "css/dark-mode.css");
        break;  
      case "blue-mode":
        document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", "css/blue-mode.css");
        break;   
    }
    

      if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
        var x = document.querySelector("#css-modes").getAttribute("href");
        localStorage.setItem("href_styles", x);

        // var z = localStorage.getItem("href_styles");
        
        document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", localStorage.href_styles);

        // document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", z);

      }
  });  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link id="css-modes" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/all.js"></script>
    <title>Mi canal de podcast</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="mi podcast">
            </div>
            <!-- <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu" class="btn-menu"> -->
            <!-- <label class="bars-open-menu" id="bars-open-menu" for="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label> -->
            <!-- <label class="x-close-menu" id="x-close-menu" for="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label> -->
            <span class="bars-open-menu" id="bars-open-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
            <span class="x-close-menu" id="x-close-menu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>

            
            <nav class="menu" id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="menu-options" href="#episodes">EPISODIOS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu-options" href="#us">NOSOTROS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu-options" href="#interviews">ENTREVISTAS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu-options" href="#topics">TÓPICOS</a></li>
                    <li id="modes-btn"><span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="modes_menu" class="modes_menu modes_menu-hide">
                    <ul>
                        <h4>Seleccione un modo</h4>
    
                        <li>
                            <label for="normal-mode">Normal mode</label>
                            <input checked type="radio" id="normal-mode" name="modes-menu" value="normal-mode">
                        </li>
                        <li> 
                            <label for="light-mode">Light mode</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="light-mode" name="modes-menu" value="light-mode">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="dark-mode">dark mode</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="dark-mode" name="modes-menu" value="dark-mode">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="blue-mode">Blue mode</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="blue-mode" name="modes-menu" value="blue-mode">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>    
    </header >
</body>
<script src="js/effects.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Agrega el codigo html de tus elementos para ver como se declararon

Comment: Hola, si se había olvidado, ya  lo agregué.

Comment: la manera de obtener un valor desde local storage es getItem por lo tanto localStorage.href_styles esto es incorrecto. la manera correcta es  localStorage.getItem("href_styles");

Comment: Hola, si igualmente lo intenté así (por eso está comentado), pero no me funciona

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza la funcion `window.onload` para que al momento de que cargue la página verifique si hay un elemento en el `localStorage` si lo hay tomará ese valor con `localStorage.getItem` y cambiará el valor del `href` y también como opcional podrías dejar el input `checked`porque hice la prueba y por default se queda marcado el primero entonces se ve medio raro cuando cambia de color.

```js
window.onload = function() {

     if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
        /*var x = document.querySelector("#css-modes").getAttribute("href");
        localStorage.setItem("href_styles", x);*/

        var z = localStorage.getItem("href_styles");
        
        console.log(z);

        //document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", localStorage.href_styles);

        document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", z);

      }
    
};


var selects_value = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for(i=0; i<selects_value.length; i++){
  selects_value[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var mode_value = this.value;

    switch (mode_value) {
      case "normal-mode":
      document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", "css/styles.css");
        break;
      case "light-mode":
        document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", "css/light-mode.css");
        break;  
      case "dark-mode":
        document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", "css/dark-mode.css");
        break;  
      case "blue-mode":
        document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", "css/blue-mode.css");
        break;   
    }
    

      if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined"){
        var x = document.querySelector("#css-modes").getAttribute("href");
        localStorage.setItem("href_styles", x);

        //var z = localStorage.getItem("href_styles");
        
        //console.log(z);

        //document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", localStorage.href_styles);

        //document.querySelector("#css-modes").setAttribute("href", z);

      }
  });  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link id="css-modes" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/all.js"></script>
    <title>Mi canal de podcast</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="mi podcast">
            </div>
            <!-- <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu" class="btn-menu"> -->
            <!-- <label class="bars-open-menu" id="bars-open-menu" for="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label> -->
            <!-- <label class="x-close-menu" id="x-close-menu" for="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label> -->
            <span class="bars-open-menu" id="bars-open-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
            <span class="x-close-menu" id="x-close-menu"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>

            
            <nav class="menu" id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="menu-options" href="#episodes">EPISODIOS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu-options" href="#us">NOSOTROS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu-options" href="#interviews">ENTREVISTAS</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu-options" href="#topics">TÓPICOS</a></li>
                    <li id="modes-btn"><span><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></span></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="modes_menu" class="modes_menu modes_menu-hide">
                    <ul>
                        <h4>Seleccione un modo</h4>
    
                        <li>
                            <label for="normal-mode">Normal mode</label>
                            <input checked type="radio" id="normal-mode" name="modes-menu" value="normal-mode">
                        </li>
                        <li> 
                            <label for="light-mode">Light mode</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="light-mode" name="modes-menu" value="light-mode">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="dark-mode">dark mode</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="dark-mode" name="modes-menu" value="dark-mode">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="blue-mode">Blue mode</label>
                            <input type="radio" id="blue-mode" name="modes-menu" value="blue-mode">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>    
    </header >
</body>
<script src="js/effects.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: El problema es que si la página se carga por primera vez o en modo incognito estos estilos  href="css/styles.css" que son los predeterminados no cargan